# Where is the default path to read config or data file in ROS when using "roslaunch" to launch the nodes?

Tags: ros

In a project , I have to use an `.so` file , and the `.so` need to load a config file that I provide. The problem is that I can not change the code of `.so` , but the `.so` load the config file in default path.
When I use `rosrun` to launch the node , I put the config file in the catkin workspace ,and when I use `./` to launch the node, I put the config file under the same folder with node. My test program is also the result.

My test code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    ros::init(argc, argv, "topic_pub");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Publisher msg_pub = nh.advertise<rostestdemo::NewMsg>("customize_msg", 20);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    rostestdemo::NewMsg msg;
    int count = 0;
    std::string filename = "hello.txt";
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(filename.c_str());
    char buf[500] = {0};
    file.getline(buf, 500);

    while(ros::ok())
    {
        msg.stamp = ros::Time::now();
        msg.data2 = count;
        msg.word = buf;
        ROS_INFO("stamp.sec = %d", msg.stamp.sec);
        ROS_INFO("stamp.nsec = %d", msg.stamp.nsec);
        ROS_INFO("data2 = %d", msg.data2);
        ROS_INFO("word = %s", msg.word.c_str());
        msg_pub.publish(msg);

        loop_rate.sleep();
        ++count;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In addition, I can use absolute path in code or param of launch file to load the file when I use `roslaunch` to launch the config file. But, when I use default path to load the file, where shuold I put the file when I use `roslaunch` ?

Answer (score 2):

You are able to search for package paths, so maybe using `ros::package::getPath('PKG_NAME')` for example, and then you concatenate the `config/your_configuration.yaml`

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion and patience with my terrible English and edit. I want to know after I find the package paths, where should I use this paths? The main problem is I can't change the code of ".so" file, in other words I can`t change the way of loading the file.

Comment: do you know where the `.so` is expecting to find the file? I couldn't understand what you mean by `default_path`. I also couldn't understand what you are trying to test

Comment: "where the `.so` is expecting to find the file" is what I want to know. Because I find that when I use the different way to launch the node, for example `roslaunch ` `rosrun` `./`, the `.so` will find the file with different path without using absolute path in code. In my test code, I don't use absolute path, just give the name of file, and then program will find the file with "defualt_path", for example, when I use `rosrun`, program will find the hello.txt in the catkin workspace, and when I use `./`, program will find the file under the same folder with node, that what I mean `default_path`.

Comment: But when I use `roslaunch`, I don't know where the path I should put the file that program expects to find. So I want to know when I use `roslaunch` to launch the node, where is the program expecting to find the file like `rosrun` or `./` without using absolute path?

Comment: I think, under the hood you are using one environment variable like `PWD`, that changes whenever you source to your `setup.bash`. Try the `~/.ros`, just in case, and the path shown in `PWD` environment variable

Comment: you can run `env | grep PWD` or `echo $PWD`

Comment: My first step is `souce devel/setup.bash` before luanch the node. I run `env | grep PWD`, it points to my catkin workspace where the node is. I think that's why when I run `rosrun` I will load file in catkin workspace.